# Webpack 5 Alias Resolution Wildcard

Tags: node.js, webpack, sass, webpack-5

I am wanting to know if some sort of wildcard is available when setting aliases in Webpack 5.

My current aliases look like so:

```js
// ...
resolve: {
  alias: {
    'scope:a$': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/@scope/package/a'),
    'scope:b$': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/@scope/package/b'),
    'scope:c$': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/@scope/package/c'),
  },
},
// ...
```

This works well. It's currently preventing Relative Path Hell in my project. I can import
:

```scss
@use 'scope:a' as a;
```

Instead of:

```scss
@use '../../../../../a' as a;
```

But I would love to solve this with one alias. Something like this:

```js
// ...
resolve: {
  alias: {
    'scope:': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/@scope/package/*'),
  },
},
// ...
```

This example implementation throws an error:

> ERROR in ...
>
> Module build failed ...
>
> ...

[Webpack's documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias) doesn't seem to mention any possible wildcard for `resolve.alias`. Does someone know if wildcards can be used in a Webpack 5 alias?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `'scope': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/@scope/package'),` and then importing as `'scope/a' as a;`, `'scope/b' as b;` etc. should work.

Answer (score 0):

As @KarloSpacapan mentioned, we can specify a directory path to `resolve.alias`

E.g.

project structure:

```
$ tree -L 2 -I node_modules
.
├── dist
│   ├── bundle.js
│   └── main.css
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── index.js
│   └── style.scss
└── webpack.config.js

2 directories, 7 files
```

Let's create a fake package named `@scope/package` containing `a.scss`, `b.scss`, and `c.scss` files inside `node_modules`.

`node_modules/@scope/package/a.scss`:

```scss
.a {
    color: red;
}
```

`node_modules/@scope/package/b.scss`:

```scss
.b {
    color: aqua;
}
```

`node_modules/@scope/package/c.scss`:

```scss
.c {
    color: beige;
}
```

`src/style.scss`:

```scss
// @use 'scope:a' as a;
// @use 'scope:b' as b;
// @use 'scope:c' as c;

@use 'scope/a' as a;
@use 'scope/b' as b;
@use 'scope/c' as c;
```

`src/index.js`:

```js
import './style.scss';
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```js
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        clean: true,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        // alias: {
        //  'scope:a$': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules@scope/package/a'),
        //  'scope:b$': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules@scope/package/b'),
        //  'scope:c$': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules@scope/package/c'),
        // },

        alias: {
            scope: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/@scope/package'),
        },
    },
    plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin()],
};
```

Build logs:

```
> webpack

asset main.css 43 bytes [compared for emit] (name: main)
asset bundle.js 0 bytes [compared for emit] [minimized] (name: main)
Entrypoint main 43 bytes = main.css 43 bytes bundle.js 0 bytes
orphan modules 2.82 KiB (javascript) 937 bytes (runtime) [orphan] 8 modules
cacheable modules 23 bytes (javascript) 42 bytes (css/mini-extract)
  ./src/index.js 23 bytes [built] [code generated]
  css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/style.scss 42 bytes [built] [code generated]

LOG from webpack.FileSystemInfo
<w> Managed item /home/lindu/workspace/webpack-samples/webpack-v5/stackoverflow/75229443/node_modules/@scope/package isn't a directory or doesn't contain a package.json (see snapshot.managedPaths option)
+ 12 hidden lines

webpack 5.88.2 compiled successfully in 421 ms
```

Output

`dist/main.css`:

```css
.a{color:red}.b{color:aqua}.c{color:beige}
```